# Wrong results while calculate sum

Tags: java, sum, calculator

I am writing a shop simulator for homework. A user inputs items for sale (set name and price) and then the user buys these items - entering ID (1-5) and count. And then - price counting (my problem).

It must be done simply, but I can't find what is wrong. The final price has strange values, and I can't understand why.

In this code I added some lines of "debugger" code, that show intermediate numbers - for best understanding of process.

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class HomeWork3Shop {

    private static Scanner inputAdmin;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] items = new String[6];
        int[] price = new int[6];

        // The administrator adds the information about the products
        System.out.println("Administrator: add five items - name and price: ");
        for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
            // if int = 0 -- will be "item 0: xxx" - not good
            System.out.print(" item " + i + ": ");
            inputAdmin = new Scanner(System.in);
            items[i] = inputAdmin.next();
            System.out.print("Price " + i + ": ");
            inputAdmin = new Scanner(System.in);
            price[i] = inputAdmin.nextInt();

        }

        int[][] buyList = new int[2][6];
        String yn = null;
        System.out.print("\nAdded. Plese buy - enter ID of item (1-5): ");

        int i = 1;
        for (int i2 = 0; i2 < 5; i2++) {
            // Enter ID of item:
            Scanner inputShoper = new Scanner(System.in);
            buyList[0][i] = inputShoper.nextInt();
            // Insert ID of item to the array - for next price count

            System.out.print("How much? (Enter a number): ");
            buyList[1][i++] = inputShoper.nextInt();
            System.out.print("\nIn bag. Want buy more? [y/n] ");

            Scanner YN = new Scanner(System.in);
            yn = YN.next();
            if (yn.equals("n")) {               
                break;
            }

            System.out.print("Enter ID of next item to buy: ");

        }


        for (int row = 0; row < buyList.length; row++) {
            // paint a table
            for (int col = 0; col < buyList[row].length; col++) {               
                System.out.print(buyList[row][col] + "\t");                   
            }             
            System.out.println();            
        }


        for (int temp = 0; temp < items.length; temp++) {              
            System.out.print(" " + items[temp]);                
        }

        for (int temp = 0; temp < items.length; temp++) {                
            System.out.print(" " + price[temp]);               
        }

        // ----- price count
        int totalPrice = 0;
        int tempPrice = 0;
        for (i = 1; i < buyList[0].length; i++) {                
            tempPrice = buyList[1][i] * price[i];
            System.out.print(" | " + tempPrice);
            totalPrice += buyList[1][i] * price[i];
            System.out.println(totalPrice);
            // count * price             
        }

        System.out.println("Your price is: " + totalPrice);

        // ----- black list -----
        System.out.print("How much money you have? ");

        int cash = 0;
        Scanner Cash = new Scanner(System.in);
        cash = Cash.nextInt();

        if (cash < totalPrice) {                
            System.out.println("You are in our Black List.");            
        }
        else {                
            System.out.println("Thank you for purchasing.");                
        }

    }

}
```

Output:

> ```
>  Administrator: add five items - name and price: 
>      item 1: Milk
>     Price 1: 11
>      item 2: Broad
>     Price 2: 22
>      item 3: Mouse
>     Price 3: 33
>      item 4: Keyboard
>     Price 4: 44
>      item 5: Monitor
>     Price 5: 55
>
>     Added. Plese buy - enter ID of item (1-5): 1
>     How much? (Enter a number): 1
>
>     In bag. Want buy more? [y/n] y
>     Enter ID of next item to buy: 2
>     How much? (Enter a number): 2
>
>     In bag. Want buy more? [y/n] y
>     Enter ID of next item to buy: 5
>     How much? (Enter a number): 4
>
>     In bag. Want buy more? [y/n] n
>     0 1   2   5   0   0   
>     0 1   2   4   0   0   
>      null Milk Broad Mouse Keyboard Monitor 0 11 22 33 44 55 | 1111
>      | 4455
>      | 132187
>      | 0187
>      | 0187
>     Your price is: 187
> ```

Final price - 187. But:

(11*1) + (22*2) + (55*4) = 22 + 44 + 220 = 286.

286 - must be, but this code get 187.

Its calculate in this line of code:

```
totalPrice += buyList[1][i] * price[i];
```

Comment: don't downvote without comment

Comment: Don't create a new `Scanner` all the time. What are the values you expect and what is output? Have you used step-by-step debugger?

Comment: Oh, I don't know about "step-by-step debugger" - can you send link?

Comment: what are "strange values" for the output?

Comment: I see a lot of array indexing starting at 1 not zero. Remember that array indexing runs from 0 to n-1 where n is the size/length of the array.

Comment: For example - 35, but must be 24.

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sW18PMBmTp4

Comment: @VitalyZdanevich tried running your code, everything seems to work correctly.  what is the input that you give that causes the output to be 35 when it should be 24?

Comment: Hard to understand your code. it's better if you post what output you want.

Comment: @Arpit Added output to the question.

Comment: @karakuricoder I start arrays from 1 just for visualization on console - item 1 price 1 instead of item 0 price 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an error in the calculation loop. You need to access the price of the item you are counting price[buyList[0][1]] instead of price[i], use this instead:

```
for (i = 1; i < buyList[0].length; i++) {
    tempPrice = buyList[1][i] * price[buyList[0][i]];
    System.out.print(" | " + tempPrice);
    totalPrice += buyList[1][i] * price[buyList[0][i]];
    System.out.println(totalPrice);
    // count * price
}
```

Apart from this, as suggested, do not create a Scanner every time, also, you already have the price in the tempPrice variable, you should not calculate that 2 times (line 2 and 4 in this code)

Hope it helps.